Gauss's school grades
Gauss attended the local Collegium Carolinum during his childhood, and then went to the University of Göttingen. But I suddenly wondered if Gauss was good at other subjects besides mathematics during his school days.
Just like Einstein's school grade cards come up a lot when we Google them, are there any papers or sites that can tell us about Gauss's school grades?

The following commentary suggests that specific grades for Gauss are not known for his period at the Carolinum. But there is a broad evaluation of his success from a brief note by Zimmermann. This passage is from:
Schlesinger, L. (1933) "Über Gauss' Arbeiten zur Funktionentheorie" in Gauss, C. F. Werke Band 10.2 Abhandlung 2:

Allerdings besitzen wir hierfür aus den nächsten Jahren keine
Zeugnisse, wir wissen nur, dass Gauss, als er 1792 vom Gymnasium
abgegangen war, einer bestehenden Verordnung gemäss, ehe er die
Universität beziehen durfte, erst noch den dreijährigen Kurs des
Collegium Carolinum absolvieren musste und dass er sich am 18. Februar
1792 in die Matrikel dieses Instituts eingeschrieben hat. Wie der
bereits erwähnte Professor Zimmermann im Jahre 1796 bezeugt 19), hat
Gauss sich auf dem Carolinum »mit ebenso glücklichem Erfolge der
Philosophie und der klassischen Literatur als der höheren Mathematik
gewidmet.«

My translation:

We do not have any evidence for the following years. We only know,
that Gauss, as he exited the Gymnasium in 1792, following an existing
ordinance, before he was allowed to enter the University, he first had
to complete a three-year program at the Collegium Carolinum, and that
he was entered in the registry of the institute on 18. February 1792.
As the already mentioned Professor Zimmermann noted in 1796 (footnote
omitted), Gauss did engage at the Carolinum "with equally happy
successes committed himself to philosophy and the classical
literature as he did with higher mathematics."

The footnoted note by Zimmermann can be found in Werke 10.1 p.3 is short (one sentence) and is in essence faithfully reproduced in Schlesinger's quote.
Schlesinger's attempt at creating a careful biography of Gauss's youth period is evidenced from other passages of the commentary. Hence it is unlikely that more detail was available to Schlesinger, and I am unaware that more detail emerged since.
All this said there is no doubt that Gauss was a kind of "wunderkind", skipped a grade and was recognized as highly gifted, receiving additional attention, leading to the guess to be sensible that his grades must have been excellent across the board.
